# clicking pagination numbers returns the previous selection (ng-bootstrap) angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, pagination, ng-bootstrap

using ng bootstrap's pagination and i want to get the page # when i click the different #s on the pagination numbers.

for example...
if there are 5 pagination when i click 2, then click 4, then 5....ill get 2 returned in my function when i click 4 will get 2 and 4 when i click 5

I want to get the exact # that i am clicking on currently not the previous #.

here's my code...

html:

```
        <ngb-pagination 
            [collectionSize]="data * 10" 
            [(page)]="page"
            [maxSize]="7"
            (click)="onPaginationClick(page)"
            aria-label="pagination">
        </ngb-pagination>
```

component:

```
  onPaginationClick(number) {
    console.log(number);
  }
```

Comment: use `(pageChange)="onPaginationClick($event)"` not (click). If you see the API https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination/api, you'll find it in the "outputs"

Comment: thanks solved the issue...